# Change the ISO 8601 date format using PHP

Tags: php, isodate

I am trying to get the current date/time using Data Type: ISODateTime and Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS e.g. 2012-02-06T08:35:30. I searched how I would do this in PHP and found that I can use;

```
$formatedDate = date("c");
```

Although the output of this is almost correct is not quite what I need and I can't figure out how to alter it, the current output of this is;

2014-07-01T10:53:10+02:00

My problem is I need to remove the "+02:00" and also this time is an hour ahead of my local time, which is what I need. Therefore, in this example, I would require;

2014-07-01T09:53:10

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just format the date manually.

```
$formattedDate =  date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

To get your local time, use [**date_default_timezone_set()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the appropriate timezone (before declaring `$formattedDate`).

```
// Change 'America/New_York' to your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/YaO7RDmH)

---

*To find your timezone, see the [List of Supported Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).*